# Can I ask here about lyrics of music and meanings?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was wondering if here is the best place to ask about lyrics of music, since I did not find any other place for that.

Comment: I love it when somebody says 'Can I ask a question?' Answer - 'you just did!' Yes, ask away. Lyrics are surely a big part of music.

Comment: Somebody should write a PhD thesis on the meaning of the lyrics in Mendelssohn's "Lieder ohne Worte." Just saying...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to exactly ask.  Asking about the meaning behind lyrics isn't really on topic here, but it is on topic on the fans site. If you want to ask more about techniques for creating lyrics along with compositional directions about lyrics then yes they are on topic.

Comment: Questions about writing lyrics are also on-topic at https://writing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -2):

Just ask your question.  If it's sensible (and answerable) someone will answer it.   If someone else then decides it's not worthy of the archive and removes it, you've still had your answer!